# Proliferating Platonic Dice

Tags: combinatorics, dice

> An unbiased single 4-sided die is thrown and its value, T, is noted.
>   T unbiased 6-sided dice are thrown and their scores are added together. The sum, C, is noted.
>   C unbiased 8-sided dice are thrown and their scores are added together. The sum, O, is noted.
>   O unbiased 12-sided dice are thrown and their scores are added together. The sum, D, is noted.
>   D unbiased 20-sided dice are thrown and their scores are added together. The sum, I, is noted.
>   Find the variance of I, and give your answer rounded to 4 decimal places.

Comment: It's [Problem #389](http://projecteuler.net/problem=389) from Project Euler.

Comment: It sure is. I am stumped.